# XcodeColors with Xcode 5.1 + crashes with iOS dev

Tags: ios, xcode

[Running OS X 10.8]

It worked fine with Xcode 5.

Now got the latest XcodeColors from GitHub (5b8da92 : Xcode 5.1 support), built it under my Xcode 5.1 environment and the TestXcodeColors app fails to write out in colour.

Worse yet, moving on to debugging my app under the iOS simulator crashes Xcode due to having the XcodeColors plug-in.  Removing it makes things work, but of course without colours in my console view.  (boo)

XcodeColors destabilizes Xcode 5.1.

Anyone else experience this or found a way to get it functioning?

Comment: I have experienced this also! Anyone?

Comment: Myself and my colleagues are experience this as well. I've submitted some crash logs to the github page.

Comment: My xcode also got crashed due to this plugin..I deleted that one..and tried to restart.But i could nt open it.Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are two possible causes for this crash: 1) OSX 10.8 2) Choosing to convert the program to ARC

A solution seems to have been found:

1) Delete your existing install of the plugin (~/Library/Application Support/developer/Shared/Xcode/plugin-ins/XcodeColors.xcplugin)

2) Download a fresh copy

3) Open it and **do not** choose to convert to ARC

If you are on 10.8:

4) Open the build settings

5) Change the Base SDK to 10.8

That's it. Otherwise, follow standard instructions (build it, restart Xcode, verify with the test program)

Comment: Well that seemed to do it, and it hasn't crashed.  Thank you!

Comment: i need to open xcode without crash...could u help me to find the way..i am faving this issue last 3 days,,not able to open xcode..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here. I just installed Xcode 5.1 with all my newly built plugins. This one crashed and I did some analysis and couldn't understand why it crashed! It all looked fine to me. I did convert the code to ARC but it didn't seem to be important for this issue.

Last resort: reboot machine. And voilà it worked! Go figure…

Ran the test and the Console output is now nicely coloured. Hope this helps you although it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Agreed. Actually I retract my answer because today Xcode started crashing again reliably. It is very weird.